# Is the set compact?

Tags: general-topology

I have $Y=(\mathbb{R},\tau)$. The open sets in this topology are $(-\infty, h), h \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then I have $S=(0,2) \cup [3,5]$. Is it compact?

Sol.:?

If I consider the subspace topology, I got that the open sets are the intersections of semirette with $S$.
If I take a open cover { $U_i$ }, I can always find a finite sub-cover by taking $U_1=(0,2) \cup [3,5)$, which is $S \cap (-\infty,5)$... but how can I take also $5$, to get $S$ compact?

Thanks

Comment: I think your title is wrong, you mean "Is it compact?"

Comment: yes, thank you:)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's worth noting that the Heine Borel Theorem does not apply to this topology.  Your set is not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take an open cover $U_{\alpha}$ then there must be some index $\alpha$ for which $5\in  U_{\alpha}$.  But then the entire set $(0,2)\cup[3,5]\subset U_{\alpha}$ so there is always a finite subcover (in fact you can always do it with one single element of the cover so definitely finite).

Comment: thanks for the answer.
Let me see if I got it.
If I take a open cover, I have to cover (of course) also $5$. But then I have  already got a finite subcover because it is $S \cup (-\infty,5+\epsilon)$. Is it right?

Comment: Exactly, you got it!

Comment: Almost.  As the only open sets are of the form $(-\infty, h)$ then $5 \in (-\infty, h) \implies h > 5$ so $(0,2) \cup [3,5] \subset (\infty, 5] \subset (-\infty, h)$.  So $(-\infty, h)$ is a finite subcover.

Comment: A non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact in this topology iff it has a largest member.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes that is also true.